# Почему при попытке наведения мыши на другой пункт меню окно пропадает?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При наведении на кнопку создается меню и убирается через 7 секунд, если с меню не воздействуют, но, как только на меню навели мышью, таймер очищается т соответственно окно надо убрать, когда пользователь перестает воздействовать с ним, проблема в том, что когда пытаешься направить мышь на другой пункт меню, само меню пропадает. Я думал, что это возможно из-за всплытия, отменил, не помогло. В чем проблема?

```js
var gear = document.querySelector('.settings__icon--3');
gear.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
 var menu = document.querySelector('.settings__hidden-menu');
 menu.style.display = 'block';
 var timeClose = setTimeout(function() {
  menu.style.display = 'none';
 }, 7000);
 menu.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  clearTimeout(timeClose);
 });
  menu.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
  menu.style.display = 'none';
    event.stopPropagation();
 });
})
```

```css
.settings__icon--3 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 40px;
}

.settings__hidden-menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="settings__icon--3">
  
</div>

<div class="settings__hidden-menu">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело не во всплытие а в поведении обработчиков `mouseover` и `mouseout`.
Смысл в том что `mouseout` вызывается всякий раз когда вы наводите курсор на любой другой элемент, даже внутри контейнера.
Решение - используйте вместо `mouseover` и `mouseout`, `mouseenter` и `mouseleave` соответственно.